# out of memory heap space error while generating pdf through itext

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext

I am trying to parse html template and converting it pdf using itex library.It is working fine in staging and qa but throwing out of memory error in production.Below is the sample code.

```
 String template = null;
  Document document = null;
  HTMLWorker htmlWorker;
  OutputStream outputStream = null;
  document = new Document();
  document.open();
  document.addTitle("SeatSeller Agent Invoice");
  document.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
  document.addHeader("name", "redbusTicket");
  document.addHeader("filename", "test.pdf");
  document.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
  document.addHeader("Content-ID", "test.pdf");
  document.addHeader("Content-Description", "SeatSellerInvoice.pdf");
  htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
  Handlebars handlebars = new Handlebars();
  String filePath = null;

    template = handlebars.compile("invoicepdftemplate").apply(creditInvoice);
    filePath = creditInvoice.getAccount().toString() + "_"
        + MMM_FORMATTER.format(creditInvoice.getDate())
        + YYYY_FORMATTER.format(creditInvoice.getDate()) + ".pdf";


  htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(template));

  document.close();

  outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

  ITextRenderer iTextRenderer = new ITextRenderer();
  iTextRenderer.setDocumentFromString(template);
  iTextRenderer.layout();
  iTextRenderer.createPDF(outputStream);
  File fileToBeUploaded = new File(filePath);
```

Below is the stacktrace of error-:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.PngImage.decodeIdat(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.PngImage.getImage(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.PngImage.getImage(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.codec.PngImage.getImage(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.startElement(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.processTag(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.go(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.parse(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.jar:na]
```

is there any memory leak or any problem in the code.Production machine memory is Xms-256  Xmx-365.Can anyone please help

Comment: at which line you got OOME? share stacktrace.

Comment: Aside from the issue at hand, you are using `HTMLWorker`. That has been superseded by `XMLWorker` in 2011.

Comment: Please follow a proper iText sample. You create an iText `Document` but don't attach a writer, so you write your PDF nowhere. Then you separately use an `ITextRenderer` which is not *part* of iText but a *wrapper* for iText functionality used by some other library. Furthermore consider updating. iText 2.1.7 is ancient.

Comment: 365Mb is quite low nowadays. Did you try to increase this value? can you configure JVM to do heapdump on OOME? This will definitely reveals root cause of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I was using 400KB size image in my html template and production machine has very less memory.So while parsing html file it was throwing out of memory error.

Answer (score -1):

outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
here:- outputStream is not closed in your code.
Please check this once or implement try with resources.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: FileOutputStream does not necessary consume heap memory. Closing it will release FD only (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/windows/native/java/io/FileOutputStream_md.c)

Comment: @rkosegi Then why OutputStream implements Closeable?

Comment: Because it needs to close FD. Check source btw. Implementing (Auto)Closeable doesn't mean that your object is consuming high amount of heap.It is contract about closing resources in general.